# Poor software raid10 read performance on Linux

Tags: linux, performance, software-raid, raid10

I've recently set up new Linux based file server. The distribution I'm using is Ubuntu 10.10. I've created two software raid devices as follows:

```
mc@vmr:~$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md0 : active raid1 sdf1[1] sdh1[3] sde1[0] sdg1[2]
  19530688 blocks [4/4] [UUUU]

md1 : active raid10 sdh3[3] sdf3[1] sde3[0] sdg3[2]
  1912461184 blocks 64K chunks 2 near-copies [4/4] [UUUU]
```

Device /dev/md0 (raid1) is mounted on "/" and /dev/md1 (raid10) is mounted on "/home".
Unfortunately the performance of my raid10 is deeply unsatisfying.
Here is the performance of each single HDD:

```
mc@vmr:~$ sudo hdparm -t /dev/sdh3  
/dev/sdh3:
 Timing buffered disk reads:  410 MB in  3.00 seconds = 136.57 MB/sec

mc@vmr:~$ sudo hdparm -t /dev/sdf3
/dev/sdf3:
 Timing buffered disk reads:  402 MB in  3.01 seconds = 133.60 MB/sec

mc@vmr:~$ sudo hdparm -t /dev/sde3
/dev/sde3:
 Timing buffered disk reads:  418 MB in  3.01 seconds = 139.10 MB/sec

mc@vmr:~$ sudo hdparm -t /dev/sdg3
/dev/sdg3:
 Timing buffered disk reads:  406 MB in  3.00 seconds = 135.32 MB/sec
```

So naturally I was expecting read performance around 260 MB/sec, but instead I've got this:

```
mc@vmr:~$ sudo hdparm -t /dev/md1
/dev/md1:
 Timing buffered disk reads:  172 MB in  3.04 seconds =  56.64 MB/sec
```

Firstly I've assumed that `hdparm` testing method is not to be 100% trusted so I did kind of real-world read test and performance was still not as expected (random.bin is placed on raid10):

```
mc@vmr:~$ dd if=random.bin of=/dev/null bs=256k
38800+0 records in
38800+0 records out
10171187200 bytes (10 GB) copied, 96.3874 s, 106 MB/s
```

Lastly I would like to share that the read performance of raid1 is exactly as expected:

```
mc@vmr:~$ sudo hdparm -t /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
 Timing buffered disk reads:  412 MB in  3.01 seconds = 136.91 MB/sec
```

Has anyone came across problem like this? Any clues?

Comment: Could you do some filesystem benchmarks on both partitions and post the results? The commands below will run iozone in automatic mode with a test file twice as large as  the amount of RAM you have.
FILESIZE=$(awk '/MemTotal/ {printf("%dg\n", $2  / 1024 / 1024 * 2)}' /proc/meminfo);  
iozone -a -n $FILESIZE -f /root/tempfile > /tmp/raid1_benchmark;  
iozone -a -n $FILESIZE -f /home/tempfile > /tmp/raid10_benchmark;

Answer (score 2):

> 64K chunks

— way too small. Almost every I/O op. has noticeable probability to involve 2 disks with such stripe size, which means more wasted I/O. My suggestion is at least 512 KiB and may be 1—2 MiB.

Also, you might find that mine [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/255008/very-low-performance-of-raid6/255031#255031) useful.

Answer (score 1):

I just created again my md1 array :

```
leo@stellie:~$ cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid1] [raid10] 
md1 : active raid10 sdc6[0] sdb6[2] sda6[1]
      32807040 blocks super 1.2 64K chunks 2 far-copies [3/3] [UUU] 
md0 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdb1[2] sdc1[1]
      248896 blocks [3/3] [UUU]
```

Notice that :
 1. metadata version was upgraded to 1.2
 2. far-copies instead of near-copies

```
leo@stellie:~$ sudo hdparm -t /dev/md1
/dev/md1:
 Timing buffered disk reads: 372 MB in  3.02 seconds = 123.29 MB/sec
```

I made some more hdparm test while the array was not yet in use and :
 - 64K chunks and near-copies performed better than before (~70MB/sec)
 - 512K chunks had lower transfer rate (~50MB/sec)
 - max read performance has been reached with far-copies and 64K chunks

As you said, I need to perform a test with iozone as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are few options

1.There a problem with:

- hard drive firmware
- firmware motherboard
- firmware sata controller
- bug in ubuntu

2.try tuning a few things

- hdparm -t --direct /dev/md0
- blockdev --setra 16384
- try bigger block with raid10 (not
  sure if its any good)

anyway hdparm is not really the best benchmark software - try bonni++ ,iozone  or dd